# Is it better to typecast 2 strings to int before comparison?

Tags: php, string, casting, int

```php
$a = '1';
$b = '1';

// Method 1
if ($a == $b) { ... }

// Method 2
if ((int)$a == (int)$b) { ... }
```

Which is the better solution? I'm thinking here of programming best practices and not necessarily performance.

Comment: [===](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: Another useful tip is not to store numerical values as string, numerical values should stay like so, they should be used as numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [Identical](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) operator.

**Edit**: Now that I look, [andre matos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/333893/andre-matos) already asserts which is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

When using '==' PHP will juggle the types around, casting them anyway.  Therefore, I can't see any advantage in casting them to integer before comparing them.

If you're looking for a more robust solution, you could cast them to integers and then use Identical ('==='), which matches both equality and type, and not Equal ('==').

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 1 == '1'; # true
echo 1 === '1'; # false
echo '1' === '1'; # true
echo '1' == '1'; # true
```